# What's the SSE equivalent of fstp?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, fpu, x87

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but fstp pops the value from the top of the FPU stack such as st0?

i.e.
    fstp tword [rsp]

If I have values in an SSE register, xmm0, what's the equivalent? I want to print the values stored in the registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSE doesn't use a stack, its registers are directly accessible.  If you want to display contents of an MMX or SSE register, then the "store" instruction is appropriate.  It will copy the values into an array of primitive data types in program memory (although in many cases you can simply cast the SSE variable in high level languages, taking its address may interfere with optimizations, by forcing a register spill to memory.  Prefer to use the load and store intrinsics.)

For example, the

```
MOVUPD
```

and

```
MOVUPS
```

instructions.

Comment: Hmm.. Could you give an example of outputting a value from an SSE register?

Comment: Is it really too hard to google for "MOVUPS example"?  Here's one that looks pretty complete: http://www.cs.uaf.edu/2011/fall/cs441/lecture/09_29_SSE.html

Comment: That requires the value to be stored in a global. Is there no way to printf from rax?

Comment: @user1787038: The example uses a global, but you can use an address relative to the stack pointer just as easily.  RAX is an integer register, you wouldn't put a floating-point value from the SIMD engine into it.

Comment: If you want to `printf()` _from assembly code_ then floating point arguments are in `%xmm0` onwards (for 1st...6th floating point arg at least). You don't need to _transfer_ them out.